# Use setInterval to infinitely draw rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas, setinterval, animated, rect

I'm trying to learn how to learn basic animation using ONLY canvas with the setInterval function.
I'm trying to draw a simple rectangle to the screen and move it to the right 1 pixel every 100 milliseconds. However when I do it paints over the previous rectangle. I called clearRect() but that doesn't seem to do anything.

How can I make this rectangle smoothly travel across the screen without leaving a trail? 
Also if there is a better way to do this rather than using clearRect() and translate() please do share.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
var a = setInterval(draw,100);

var x = 50;
function draw()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    ctx.translate(1,0);
    ctx.rect(x,50,50,50);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Which part did you think was moving this one pixel to the right?

Comment: @lwburk The translate part moves it, but it's a bad approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it two different ways:

You can continue to use `rect()` and `stroke()`, but you need to call `beginPath()` beforehand.  When you call methods like `rect()`, a list, called the "path," is kept of all of the shapes, or "subpaths," that you've created.  Then, when you call `stroke()`, the *entire* path is drawn.  Thus, even if you clear the screen, all of the past rectangles are still remembered in the path, and drawn again.  `beginPath()` clears that list.

```
var x = 50;
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(x, 50, 50, 50);
    ctx.stroke();
    x++;
}
```

Or, you can combine the `rect()` and `stroke()` into one line, and not need to call `beginPath()`.  That's because the rectangle is both created and drawn at the same time, and isn't put in the list.

```
var x = 50;
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
    ctx.strokeRect(x, 50, 50, 50);
    x++;
}
```

Either way, I advise incrementing `x` instead of using `translate()`, because `translate()` basically moves the imaginary "pen" that is drawing on the canvas.  So if you `translate(50, 50)`, and then you try to draw a rectangle at (0, 0) on the canvas, it will actually be at (50, 50).

As [Microsoft puts it on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975435(v=vs.85).aspx), "The translate method effectively remaps the (0,0) origin on a canvas."

If you repeatedly do that, it will become difficult to keep track of where you're actually drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `x` variable never changes, so your shape will not move. You need to increment x to get movement:

```
var x = 50;
function draw(){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    ctx.translate(1,0);
    ctx.rect(x,50,50,50);
    ctx.stroke();
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a smooth animation with shapes and other sprites moving across the screen (or even staying still) it would be better to make a `clearScreen` method that will basically draw over the entire canvas in whatever background color the canvas is. It is basically just a function that will draw a white (or whatever background color you are using) rectangle over the entire canvas. Then, you call the draw function that will make all the necessary drawings. That way, there won't be any trail or anything of the past movements and you won't have to call `clearRect()` on every single rectangle you make.

Basically, the function will erase the canvas and you can redraw whatever you need to in order to make the animation of the box moving across the screen.

Does that make sense?

EDIT:
Also, to be clear, you would make your own `clearScreen` method based on what size your canvas is and what color your background is. Its not hard, all it does is draw a rectangle over the screen.

Comment: @Shomz oh my apologies, I thought that clearRect was being used to clear the rectangle that is moving, not the entire screen. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, 300px is usually the default canvas width. I prefer clearing it by resetting its width or height.

Answer (score 0):

Simply increment `x` on every call:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var a = setInterval(draw,100);

        var x = 50;
        function draw(){
            canvas.width = canvas.width; // clears the canvas
            ctx.rect(x++,50,50,50);
            ctx.stroke();
            if (x > 250) // resets the position
              x = 50;
        }
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

I also removed that translation since there's no need to do it just for the square animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try beginPath() and closePath():

```js
var maxX, x = 0,
  s = 50,
  maxY;

var repaint = function(ctx) {
  if (x + s >= maxX) { //reached end of the canvas
    return;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, maxX, maxY); //clear previous
  ctx.beginPath(); //start drawing
  ctx.rect(x, s, s, s);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath(); //stop drawing
  x++;
  setTimeout(function() {
    repaint(ctx); //continue here
  }, 100);
};

var cnvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
maxX = cnvs.width;
maxY = cnvs.height;
repaint(cnvs.getContext('2d'));
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="360" height="180" id='canvas'>HTML5 canvas not supported</canvas>
```